# How do I know if an object can be weakly referenced?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

[Foundation Release Notes for OS X v10.11 and iOS 9: NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter) says: "If an object can be weakly referenced notifications will no longer be sent to the observer during deallocation." How can I tell "if an object can be weakly referenced"?

Answer (score 4):

There is some information on this in the [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#weak-unavailable-types):

> It is explicitly permitted for Objective-C classes to not support
>   __weak references. It is undefined behavior to perform an operation with weak assignment semantics with a pointer to an Objective-C object
>   whose class does not support __weak references.
>
> Rationale
>
> Historically, it has been possible for a class to provide its own
>   reference-count implementation by overriding retain, release, etc.
>   However, weak references to an object require coordination with its
>   class’s reference-count implementation because, among other things,
>   weak loads and stores must be atomic with respect to the final
>   release. Therefore, existing custom reference-count implementations
>   will generally not support weak references without additional effort.
>   This is unavoidable without breaking binary compatibility.
>
> A class may indicate that it does not support weak references by
>   providing the objc_arc_weak_reference_unavailable attribute on the
>   class’s interface declaration. A retainable object pointer type is
>   weak-unavailable if is a pointer to an (optionally protocol-qualified)
>   Objective-C class T where T or one of its superclasses has the
>   objc_arc_weak_reference_unavailable attribute. A program is ill-formed
>   if it applies the __weak ownership qualifier to a weak-unavailable
>   type or if the value operand of a weak assignment operation has a
>   weak-unavailable type.

Additionally, assuming it's still current, [Transitioning to ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW17) says:

> Which classes don’t support weak references?
>
> You cannot currently create weak references to instances of the
>   following classes:
>
> NSATSTypesetter, NSColorSpace, NSFont, NSMenuView, NSParagraphStyle,
>   NSSimpleHorizontalTypesetter, and NSTextView.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, every object *you* know about *can* be weakly referenced. The previous sentence in the docs describes the exceptions to the rule: "i.e. it has a custom retain/release mechanism that would prevent the runtime from being able to store the object weakly". No object that you are likely to want to register fits that description.

Comment: By the way, thanks for pointing out this note. I didn't realize we no longer needed to deregister manually.

Comment: Sure thing! Thank you for your answer. :-)